# git: How to get the new develop branch after merging a pull request?

Tags: git, branch

I did a git clone of a repo, then git checkout develop
Then I created a feature branch, made some changes, committed it and pushed it back to github.  Then, in github, I then did a pull request to pull it to develop, merged to develop. If I go onto github website, and select develop branch, I see my changes in the source.

But I cant find a way to get the new develop branch back on to my mac.

If I do git fetch, I get no errors. I then do git checkout develop, but I just see my old code.  Obviously I havent made any changes to develop on my machine, they only happened inside github via pull request/merge.

How do I get the new develop branch?

I took a guess at "git merge develop", although this would seem wrong there is nothing to merge, I just want to checkout develop from the fetched updates. "git merge develop" just says "already up to date", although it is not.

I also tried doing a git pull.  This gives an error message, and suggest:

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/ develop

This seems rather drastic, and I don't know what side effects this will have down the line.

Obviously, I can resort to deleting the entire project, and cloning from scratch, but I presume there is an easier way?

FYI, on a server, I tried doing a git clone followed by git checkout develop, and I see the new code.

Also, on my mac, if I do "git status" it says:

On branch develop,
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Note also that I am not working from a fork, but doing branches directly on the main (and only) github repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have done:

```
git checkout develop
git pull
```

That would have fetched+merge.

In your current situation, you still can do:

```
git checkout develop
git fetch
git merge origin/develop
```

Comment: thanks for the help. So you are saying 1) if are on develop branch, then you do git fetch, you cant do git pull (I tried this, it gives errors). But if you dont do git fetch, it works?  2) I tried git merge origin/develop, and it has listed hundreds of changes. This is wrong - I only changed 1 file!  If I do a comparison in github of my branch and develop, it only shows one file changed.  I have been unable to find a "recipe" or user guide for working with develop branch which includes pulling updates, unfortunately.

Comment: @JohnLittle If you don't have any new commits or current change in your develop branch, you can reset it to origin/develop: git checkout develop + git reset --hard origin/develop. Again: make sure you don't have work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

You can either *delete* your own `develop`, then `git checkout develop` again, or—at least sometimes / usually—just do this:

```
$ git fetch              # if needed
$ git checkout develop
$ git merge
```

In fact, though, you don't even *need* your own `develop`.

All becomes clear once you understand that in Git, the branch *names* are just pointers.  What really matters, in Git, are the *commits*.  Each name—whether it's a branch name like `develop` or `master`, or a *remote-tracking* name like `origin/develop`—simply points to one commit.  The commits represent the substance; the names are just how Git *finds* the commits.

Let's look at what you had when you started, but let's begin by drawing the commits.  Each commit has some big ugly hash ID as its true name, but these are too unwieldy for mere humans, so let's use single uppercase letters to represent commits.  Let's also note that each commit records the hash ID of its *parent* commit.  When something holds the hash ID of a commit, we say that this thing *points to* the commit.  So if commit `A` comes first, and then `B` remember's `A`'s hash ID, `B` points to `A`:

```
A <--B <--C
```

and so on.  Because new commits link to old ones (not old ones to new ones), and because nothing can ever *change* inside a commit once the commit is made, these arrows always point backwards, so we can just draw them as lines for convenience.

Because the hash IDs seem random, Git—and you—need some sort of name to hold the hash ID of the *last* commit:

```
A--B--C   <-- origin/develop
```

Multiple names can hold the same hash ID, as is the case if you now run `git checkout develop`, which notices that you don't *have* a `develop`, but that you do have an `origin/develop`, so it *creates* your `develop` now:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

(Git attaches the word `HEAD` to one branch to remember which branch is your active, current branch.  It's a good idea to include it in your drawings.)

If you now create a feature branch `feature`, Git makes it point to commit `C` as well:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, feature (HEAD), origin/develop
```

When you make *new* commits, Git creates the new commit pointing back to the current commit—commit `C`, found via `HEAD`—and then updates the current name, found via `HEAD`, so that it points to the *new* commit that points back to `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, origin/develop
       \
        D   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

You now `git push feature` to GitHub, which creates a branch named `feature` on the other Git that your Git calls `origin`, so now *you* have:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, origin/develop
       \
        D   <-- feature (HEAD), origin/feature
```

Note that your Git is simply remembering where *their* Git's branches are / were, via these `origin/` names.

Someone now merges your commit into `develop` on origin.  The result is—well, *might* be, depending on how this "someone" has done the operation on GitHub—drawn like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop
       \
        D   <-- feature (HEAD), origin/develop, origin/feature
```

If you now `git checkout develop` to attach `HEAD` to `develop`, you get:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop (HEAD)
       \
        D   <-- feature, origin/develop, origin/feature
```

And if you now ask your Git to merge your `develop` with `origin/develop`, your Git notices that it can do this as a fast-forward operation—not a merge, really—which produces:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD), feature, origin/develop, origin/feature
```

But note that if you simply *delete* the name `develop`, without attaching `HEAD` to it, you get:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- feature (HEAD), origin/develop, origin/feature
```

which in some senses is just as good.  If you want to now create `feature2`, you can create that branch name now, and delete `feature` and `git push --delete origin feature`, giving:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- feature2 (HEAD), origin/develop
```

Notice how the *commits* remain inviolate at all times.  Commits are the reason Git exists.  The branch and remote-tracking names *change*, all the time.  Branch names in particular change by the very act of you making a new commit.  Your remote-tracking names change when you `git push` successfully—your Git knows that their Git has accepted the new commit into their branch-name—and when you `git fetch` because your Git just got all their latest commits and knows where their branch names are now.  These are the parts that move.  Commits don't move: they just accumulate over time.